# WCF REST service. Operation start and finish time

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

I got a WCF RESTful web-service and I am wondering is it possible to log current time right before every method call and right after every method call (I mean methods defined in some operation contract). I don't wanna include logging inside methods themselves.
I need to do logging on server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF apps don't write logs, unless you've adding logging to them. check it out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx
you can try to add listener at your configuration xml file.

```
<configuration>
   <system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add name="traceListener" 
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                   initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
      </sources>
   </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I could use this way, but I am not satisfied with default info, I want to get detailed and formatted info like which params were passed to a method and so on...

Comment: ok i understand. Also you should add new WCf pipeline. for example; your new pipeline works as logger when before all method invocation. http://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2010/12/04/extending-wcf-creating-a-logging-component/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following simple method for testing and not production:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

stringBuilder.AppendLine(DateTime.Now.ToString()); //START
wcfService.ActionCallMethod(); //THIS IS AN EXAMPLE SERVICE CALL WHERE YOU WILL MAKE THE CALL
stringBuilder.AppendLine(DateTime.Now.ToString()); //END

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\logfile.txt", stringBuilder.ToString());
```

You can also replace the file with a database write/log action. I would suggest to create a custom class that you can call passing a datetime stamp that gets persisted to the database custom log table.

I would combine this with a WCF svclog file during development and testing to ensure no stone if left un-turned.

[**Configuring WCF Tracing**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)

Comment: you should place the code when you call the WCF service method. I made a comment `//Execute the service...` - This is where you must call the service.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. I need to do logging on the server side.

Comment: The above is server side.Inside the WCF service method it will execute code as well so from the START time to the END time should tell you how long the service executes server side.

Comment: But I don't wanna place code like that in every method, I am wondering is there any way to be notified about "someone has just called method "Foo" of my web-service" event -> log this event.

Comment: The use WCF Tracing as I mentioned at the bottom. That will log every call using only config setting and not code

Comment: I could use this way, but I am not satisfied with default info, I want to get detailed and formatted info like which params were passed to a method and so on...